# Ridge, Lasso, and Ridge in stats-models package

Tags: statsmodels

I am using the stats models package for Ridge, Lasso, and Elastic Net and refer to the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html).

1. My Ridge regression hyper-parameters:
   L1_wt = 0, and then method = 'sqrt_lasso'
2. My Lasso regression hyper-parameters:
   L1_wt = 1, and then method = 'sqrt_lasso'

But I get almost the same results (not exact, but very close)

Then, trying the following hyper-parameters produces different results:

3. L1_wt = 0.02, and then method = 'elastic_net'

My question: I think I miss something and use the wrong hyper-parameters for ridge regression (the example 1) The documentation does not specify it explicitly - my guess is to get the ridge results I need to use the following hyper-parameters:

L1_wt = 0, and then method = 'elastic_net'

Can anyone confirm that this?

Comment: How did you set the penalization weight alpha?

Comment: alpha is 100 for both Lasso and Ridge (ex 1 and ex 2)

Comment: Did you increase alpha to see if difference between ridge and lasso becomes larger. Ridge does not set parameters to zero, so the difference with large penalties should be visible. Your usage of L1_wt looks correct.

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate it. I think this now makes sense.